# Override Laravel 4 Package view

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel, laravel-4

I want to create my custom CMS and I'd like to create a user package in which I will have a controller with showProfile() function. But the problem is I'd like to easily edit this profile view. So I want to know if there is a way to create cascade view. Like if there is no file in app/views/ then vendor/vendor/package/src/views will be loaded. I hope you got this idea :)

EDIT:

I managed to make it work. I had to register new namespace for views in my ServiceProvider.
I put this code to ServiceProvider:

```
\View::addNamespace('cmscore',array(app_path()./'views/packages/zaalbarxx/cmscore');
```

Where zaalbarxx/cmscore is vendor/package and cmscore is a namespace I can use later in controller like View::make('cmscore::index'). I added this code in boot() method BEFORE $this->package() so this way app/views are prioritized over package/views. Works brilliant.

Comment: Good find, thanks for posting a solution

Answer (score 4):

It is already possible, however the structure would be it look into `vendor/package-name/src/views` by default, but if there is the equivalent in `app/views/packages/package-name/` that would be chosen.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, you should be able to load package views already.

However, you can add more view locations in the array found in [app/config/view.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/config/view.php).

Additionally view paths can be added at run-time with the [addLocation()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php#L147) method found in the `FileViewFinder` class.

Using that method that in a service provider would look like:

```
$app['view.finder']->addLocation('/path/to/views');
```

Or anywhere in your app:

```
App::make('view.finder')->addLocation('/path/to/views');
```

Also note, I answered [this question on cacheing view output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460157/caching-view-output-in-laravel-4/17508295#17508295) recently, which might help you see how extending some portions of the View package might work if you choose to go down that route.

Comment: Do note that package view can only cascaded to `app/views` as of now, as this location are hard-coded from `Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::package()`.

Comment: Yes, I have no problem with loading views from certain package. But I would like to create just simple view in package and then have ability to move it to app/views and extend. Or should I just not create view in package and force user to create file in app/views in order to use this profile() controller method ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to program this behavior in, if you read the laravel code you will see that this is built in...

Packages by default will first look in and 
`app/views/packages/package-name/` (all in lowercase! even if package or author have caps! goes unnoticed on windows and then on linux you will bump your head against the wall! )

and if the customer app view doesn't exist the package views will load from the package itself inside: 
`vendor/author/package-name/src/views`

Comment: Note that the custom path is not `...packages/package-name...` but rather `...packages/vendor/package-name...` (note the **vendor** part). You can publish package views for modification using the `php artisan view:publish vendor/package` command. Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/4.1/packages#package-views

Comment: Another gotcha: `view:publish` command sometimes create folders in title case, e.g. `app/views/packages/Vendor/Package`. But that may not be picked up by the server and you might need to rename the folder to `.../vendor/package`.